# Crossrider Extension Platform

Tags: javascript, api, cross-browser, browser-extension, crossrider

I'm creating an extension using Crossrider that allows users to bookmark the page they are viewing.

For this purpose, I created a button popup that when clicked opens with the UI for managing the list of bookmarks. When the user clicks on the extension's button I want to pass the URL of the page being viewed to the popup so that I can add it to the list of bookmarks. My problem is that I don't know how to pass the URL to the popup. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The following snippet is a simplified version of the code to demonstrate what I have:

background.js:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('images/icon.png');
    appAPI.browserAction.setPopup({
        resourcePath:'html/popup.html',
        height: 300,
        width: 300
    });
});
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- This meta tag is relevant only for IE -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function crossriderMain($) {
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bookmark List</h1>
<ul>
    <li>1: http://example.com/1.html</html>
    <li>2: http://example.com/2.html</html>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is [scope](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/scopes). The scope the popup runs in does not have access to the URL of the page being viewed; hence, to get the URL to the popup scope, the popup code must request the information from another scope via [messaging](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message).

The simplest way to do this is for the popup to send a message to the active tab ([Extension Page Scope](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/guide/scopes_extension)) requesting the URL of the page it's displaying. You can achieve this as follows and I'll leave you to do the code for adding the bookmark to your list.

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  // Listener to receive messages
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    // check if message is requesting page url and respond accordingly
    if (msg.type==='get-url')
      appAPI.message.toPopup({
        url:encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
      });
  });
  // The rest of your code
  ...
});
```

**popup.html**:

```
...
function crossriderMain($) {
  // Listener to receive messages
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    // check if message contains a url and call function to process the url
    if (msg.url) addBookmark(msg.url);
  });
  // Request url from active tab
  appAPI.message.toActiveTab({
    type: 'get-url';
  });
  function addBookmark(url) {
    // Add your code that handles adding the url to the bookmark list
  }
}
...
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]